# How do I check what tableview is the current one in a segue

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uistoryboardsegue

How do I check what tableview is the current one in a segue?
Since UISearchDisplayController activates its own tableview, I get another array with results.

This is the code I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetails"]) {        
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];    
        if (self.tableView == [[self searchDisplayController]searchResultsTableView]) {
        }
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.myObject = [mySearchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to Apple website](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), inside the method:

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {...}`

you would check the tableView

```
if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    return ...;
}
// If necessary (if self is the data source for other table views),
// check whether tableView is searchController.searchResultsTableView.
return ...;
```